# MultipleQueriesSeparator is missing from NHibernate IDriver interface as of version 3.2

Tags: c#, nhibernate, blob

I am trying to recompile `Calyptus.Lob` using NHibernate 3.2 , but the `IDriver` interface no longer has `MultipleQueriesSeparator` member .  What can I do about it to overcome the problem ?

For Calyptus.Lob see [this](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/03/large-object-storage-for-nhibernate-and-ddd-part-1-blobs-clobs-and-xlobs/)

I am also interest in alternatives to Calyptus.Lob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change happened in March, as part of the solution for [this issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2605).

[Here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/2e3df20898fba0136b5b6c7ddf0a4bb8d75c43ab)'s the corresponding ChangeSet. You can take a look at how the different drivers were changed to support this, and implement it for Calyptus.Lob.